# Multiline text in multiline equation

Tags: header-footer, cases

I have an assignment to copy the picture below in LaTeX. I got stuck with the (A.4) equation in attached picture. Specifically, I need the text part of that equation to be in two lines but the way I did it the text just goes through the margins.
I used `itemize` for the numbering and `dcases*` for the equation.

Also as a bonus question, I'm not sure how to do the footer copyright exactly as on the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Text in two lines

This can be realized in lots of ways.

**Environment `tabular`:**

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}
  First line\\
  Second line
\end{tabular}
```

However the `tabular` environment sets `\struts` to enforce full line heights and depths. In this case I would go for the other options.

**Environment `minipage`:**

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{123pt}% a magic number
  First line\\
  Second line
\end{minipage}
```

Disadvantage: The width of the `minipage` is set manually.

**Environment `varwdith`:**

```
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
  First line\\
  Second line
\end{varwidth}
```

The advantage of `varwidth` over `minipage` is that `varwidth` automatically shrinks the width of the lines.

**`\oalign`:**

```
\oalign{%
  First line\hfil\cr
  Second line\hfil
}%
```

`\oalign` is automatically top aligned and the lines are separated by a vertical space of `0.25ex`.

### Extra space in `cases` between lines

The case lines of environment `cases` of `(A.4)` are additionally separated
by extra vertical space. This is achieved by

```
\noalign{\kern1ex}
```

to insert vertical space between the cases lines.

The optional argument of `\\` does not work well, if the depth of the line is larger than the depth of the inserted strut.

### Equation number left below

The reading order is organized in lines from left to right and the lines are read from top to bottom. If the equation number should go to the left side, it means the equation number goes *before* the equation. If the equation number needs to be shifted vertically, because the equation is too large, then `amsmath` puts the equation number above the equation to preserve the reading order: first equation number, then equation.

Otherwise, if the equation should come first, I would not use `leqno`, but would go for the default, option `reqno` (equation numbering to the right).

Nevertheless the internals of package `amsmath` can be tweaked to put the shifted equation number below if option `leqno` is active. The example shows this for environment `gather`. Environment `align` might work also, but there
are some cases left, e.g. probably `multline` stuff.

### Footer

The copyright notice can be put into `\fancyfoot[R]` of package `fancyhdr`. 
The example just redefines page style `plain`. But this can be done differently, the point is the code inside `\fancyfoot[R]`. The two lines are set via a `tabular`. The base line of the top line is aligned with the
base line of the page number.

### Example

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{textcomp}% better copyright symbol
% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[C]{\textsf{\thepage}}%
  \fancyfoot[R]{%
    \sffamily
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}%
      Copyright \textcopyright\space by \dots\\
      Unauthorized reproduction of this article is prohibited.%
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand*{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\place@tag@gather{%
  \iftagsleft@
    \kern-\gdisplaywidth@
    \ifshifttag@
      \rlap{\vtop{%
        \raise@tag
        \normalbaselines
        \setbox\@ne\null
        \dp\@ne\lineht@
        \box\@ne
        \boxz@
      }}%
%      \rlap{\vbox{%
%        \normalbaselines
%        \boxz@
%        \vbox to\lineht@{}%
%        \raise@tag
%      }}%
      \global\shifttag@false
    \else
      \rlap{\boxz@}%
    \fi
  \else
    \ifdim\totwidth@>\displaywidth
      \dimen@\totwidth@
      \advance\dimen@-\displaywidth
      \kern-\dimen@
    \fi
    \ifshifttag@
      \llap{\vtop{%
        \raise@tag
        \normalbaselines
        \setbox\@ne\null
        \dp\@ne\lineht@
        \box\@ne
        \boxz@
      }}%
      \global\shifttag@false
    \else
      \llap{\boxz@}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\def\set@gather@field{%
  \global\lineht@\dp\z@
  \kern\eqnshift@
  \boxz@
  \hfil
}
\def\place@tag{%
  \iftagsleft@
    \kern-\tagshift@
    \if1\shift@tag\row@\relax
      \rlap{\vtop{%
        \raise@tag
        \normalbaselines
        \setbox\@ne\null
        \dp\@ne\lineht@
        \box\@ne
        \boxz@
      }}%
%      \rlap{\vbox{%
%        \normalbaselines
%        \boxz@
%        \vbox to\lineht@{}%
%        \raise@tag
%      }}%
    \else
      \rlap{\boxz@}%
    \fi
    \kern\displaywidth@
  \else
    \kern-\tagshift@
    \if1\shift@tag\row@\relax
      \llap{\vtop{%
        \raise@tag
        \normalbaselines
        \setbox\@ne\null
        \dp\@ne\lineht@
        \box\@ne
        \boxz@
      }}%
    \else
      \llap{\boxz@}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\def\set@field{%
  \column@plus
  \ifdim\dp\z@>\lineht@
    \global\lineht@\dp\z@
  \fi
  \boxz@
}
\renewcommand{\raisetag}[1]{\skip@#1\relax
  \xdef\raise@tag{\vskip-\the\skip@\relax}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{743}
\renewcommand*{\theequation}{A.\arabic{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{3}
\null\newpage
\vspace*{\fill}

\begin{gather}
  \hat\omega_{ij} =
  \begin{cases}
    \min\{
      \hat\omega^A_{ij} / \hat\omega^B_{ij},
      \hat\omega^B_{ij} / \hat\omega^A_{ij}
    \}
%    & \oalign{if $\hat\omega^A_{ij}$ and $\hat\omega^B_{ij}$ have\cr
%      the same sign\hfil}
    & \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
      if $\hat\omega^A_{ij}$ and $\hat\omega^B_{ij}$ have\\
      the same sign
    \end{varwidth}
    \\
    \noalign{\kern1ex}
    \max\{
      \hat\omega^A_{ij} / \hat\omega^B_{ij},
      \hat\omega^B_{ij} / \hat\omega^A_{ij}
    \}
%    & \oalign{if $\hat\omega^A_{ij}$ and $\hat\omega^B_{ij}$ have\cr
%      the opposite signs\hfil}
    & \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
      if $\hat\omega^A_{ij}$ and $\hat\omega^B_{ij}$ have\\
      the opposite signs
    \end{varwidth}
    \\
    \noalign{\kern1ex}
    1 & \text{if } \hat\omega^A_{ij} = \hat\omega^B_{ij} = 0 \\
    \noalign{\kern1ex}
    0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\\
  \hat\omega^A_{ij} =
  \begin{cases}
    \dfrac{a_i - a_j}{a_{\text{max}} - a_{\text{min}}}
    & \text{if } a_{\text{max}} \ne a_{\text{min}}
    \\
    \noalign{\kern1ex}
    0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\\
  \hat\omega^B_{ij} =
  \begin{cases}
    \dfrac{b_i - b_j}{b_{\text{max}} - b_{\text{min}}}
    & \text{if } b_{\text{max}} \ne b_{\text{min}}
    \\
    \noalign{\kern1ex}
    0 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

A simple method is to use parboxes. You just have to play around with the width to get line breaks that look ok.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{equation*}
a =
\begin{dcases}
b^2 + c^2 + d^2 & \parbox{125pt}{quite a long description really} \\
e & \parbox{125pt}{another fairly long description}
\end{dcases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image: cases]

**EDIT**

You can use the `[leqno]` option for mathtools to put the numbers on the left. However, this places the numbers for long equations above left. To move a number below left, you could use an `align` environment with an empty bottom line (an old trick from the days when I still used `eqnarray`).

```
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{mathtools}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{align}
a =
\begin{dcases}
b^2 + c^2 + d^2 & \parbox{125pt}{quite a long description really} \\
e & \parbox{125pt}{another fairly long description}
\end{dcases} \nonumber \\
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: cases2]

Comment: And you can align them with `\parbox[t]{…` for instance.

Comment: Yes that really helped, but I have another problem now. How do I make the (A.4) numbering appear at the lower left part of the equation like in the picture. I was using itemize and \item[(A.4)] to make the numbering look like that

Comment: @Matija --- I have edited my answer.